# Getting error while setting up Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I am getting the following error while setting up ambari:

```
ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1. 
REASON: Before starting Ambari Server, you must copy the Oracle JDBC driver JAR file to /usr/share/java.
```

I have placed the jdbc-oracle.jar file to /usr/share/java location but still getting this error. Kindly guide me how to resolve this issue and proceed towards setting up Ambari for my hadoop single node cluster and running some services(e.g spark) on it.

Answer (score 1):

From Ambari source code, Oracle jdbc driver should have name `ojdbc6.jar` and be located at `/usr/share/java`

Comment: I am now trying to start with postgres. But still getting error `"Ambari Server java process died with exitcode 1. Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information."`

In logs the error was: `"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."`

postgresql-42.1.4.jar is present in /usr/share/java directory and also hostname:port is localhost:8080.

Comment: I have Followed steps from [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.1.0/bk_ambari-administration/content/using_ambari_with_postgresql.html)

Comment: localhost:8080 sounds like a web interface port. Postgres port is usually 5432